# How to compute $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{\arctan (n)}}{{5n}}$?

Tags: calculus

What is the limit of the sequence of $\frac{{\arctan (n)}}{{5n}}$ as $n\to \infty$ ?

What I found so far is that I use L'Hopital's rule to find the derivative of both top and bottom.

I end up getting that the answer is $1\over5$. Is this correct?
And how do you find if the sequence is monotonic or not?

Comment: the limit as $n$ approaches what?

Comment: The limit as n approaches infinity

Comment: But $arctan(\infty)=\frac {\pi}2$ so the numerator approaches a finite constant while the denominator grows without bound,

Comment: @user283466 can you show us how to get $\frac{1}{5}$

Comment: i got $0$ for the searched limit

Comment: As pointed out by lulu, the answer is clear without calculation, so L'H Rule should really not have been used. However, if applied correctly, it will work. When applying it, you should have ended up looking at $\frac{1/(1+x^2)} {5}$  as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: @user283466: Hey OP! Are you there? :)

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much I understand this question now!!!

Comment: @user283466: will you please check mark some answers! Notice check-marks next to answers. :)

Answer (score 5):

You **cannot** use Hospital's rule as this is **not** an in-determinant form! In this case you should use the **limit theorem for products** according to

$$\begin{array}{l}
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \arctan (n) = \frac{\pi }{2}\\
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{1}{{5n}} = 0
\end{array}$$

and hence

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \frac{{\arctan (n)}}{{5n}} = 0$$

Answer (score 4):

Notice, l'Hospital's rule is applicable for $\frac{0}{0}$ form but as $n\to \infty\implies \tan^{-1}(n)\to \frac{\pi}{2}$ which is a finite non-zero value hence l'Hospital's rule is not applicable. You should follow the following method  $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\tan^{-1}(n)}{5n}$$

$$=\frac{1}{5}\lim_{n\to \infty}\tan^{-1}(n)\cdot \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}$$

$$=\frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\cdot(0)=\color{red}{0}$$
So your answer $\frac{1}{5}$ is not correct